# Spring MVC Autowired null in Component

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

My component is:

```
package com.netpc.recruitment.models.user;
@Component
public class UserAuth {
    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userDAO;
}
```

Vars `httpSession` and `userDAO`, while creating object in controllers, are `null`. `userDAO` is configured properly and it works fine in my `com.netpc.recruitment.controllers.IndexController` class `@Controller`.

My web.xml

```
<beans ......>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.netpc.recruitment.controllers" />
    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.netpc.recruitment.models.user.JDBCUserDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Whats wrong with it? Why it's `null`?

Comment: Did you scan for components the package in which `UserAuth` is located?

Comment: **while creating object in controllers**. Well sure they are null, you are creating new instances yourself instead of letting the Spring container do it. Also injecting the `HttpSession` seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: tried to make `<context:component-scan base-package="com.netpc.recruitment.controllers, com.netpc.recruitment.models" />` - no luck

Comment: @M.Deinum understood. i'm a big newbie to Spring. Can u suggest how to make `UserAuth` (login/logout users) works fine? Firstly, i did it as a singleton. It looks fine, but not for DI of Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component scan is scanning only on "com.netpc.recruitment.controllers". Should also scan in package com.netpc.recruitment.models.user. Changes in web.xml:

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.netpc.recruitment.controllers" />
```

to this:

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.netpc.recruitment.controllers, com.netpc.recruitment.models.user" />
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Also classnames: Try to use JDBCUserDAO userDAO; instead of IUserDAO userDAO, just for testing

Comment: And where is your HttpSession defined?

Comment: does't work.
HttpSession is javax.servlet.http.HttpSession
no difference to name.

Comment: You can't just inject a HttpSession when you feel like it I think.. :). Anyway, it's sure that you have to add the second package to component scan, else it will never work. Is the correct Component package included in your class? (The annotation?).. This one: import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

Comment: Changes can be at dispatcher-servlet.xml